# Id class membership in R poLCA

Tags: r

I am running a latent class analysis in R with and all runs fine and I get my final class model. Now I need to look at class membership, so I used the following code:

```
  round(lca.raq2 $posterior[1:3413,],2)
```

The problem is R eliminated cases from my original file (potentially problem cases for the model?) so I have no way of identifying which probabilities correspond to each case in my original database.

Is there anyway to include my id_variable in the $posterior command??

I tried merging the ID with the dataset produced by poLCA but it doesn't merge and gives me this error:

> merge(lca.raq, homdata$idnumber)
>   Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
>     cannot coerce class ‘"poLCA"’ to a data.frame

Any suggestions are welcome - I really need to be able to identify the specific cases in each class to run further analysis with the classes.

Comment: From the documentation it seems na values are removed. Possibly your dataset contains missing if null values. In this case `homdata[complete.cases(homdata),]` would be the data used during estimation.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the row names from lca.raq2$y. Like @Oliver said, NA values are taken out, so you are left with a subset of your values. You can see below example to see how to get the id or observation names out. I suggest naming the rows of your input data after your id.

```
library(poLCA)
set.seed(123)
data(values)
#introduce some random NAs
# here it set the rownames of the matrix to be id
# in your case it might be homdata$idnumber
rownames(values) = paste("row",1:nrow(values),sep="")
for(i in 1:ncol(values)){
 values[sample(1:nrow(values),10),i]<-NA
 }
 f <- cbind(A,B,C,D)~1
M1 <- poLCA(f,values,nclass=2)

POST = round(M1$posterior,2)
rownames(POST) = rownames(M1$y)

# we can check that the rownames of posterior values are indeed those complete values in original data
table(rownames(values)[complete.cases(values)] == rownames(POST))
TRUE 
 183
```